# Android resources in library not inherited by library consumer when running in Android1.5

Tags: android, inheritance, resources

I have a common library I use for apps of a similar type. The library has png files in the res/drawable-hdpi folder, as they are used by in all the other apps that use the library, so I don't have to keep copies in each application.

It seems that in Android 1.5, the drawable resources from the library are NOT inherited when the application imports the library, but does in all versions beyond Android 1.5. My application runs, and I immediately get a ResourceNotFoundException when an activity that uses the resource is loaded. Is there a way I can specify the resources as public or available in some way? I specified Activities in the library within the Android Manifest so they could be run by users of the library. Is there a way to do that with resources?  Also, why is this only happening with Androi 1.5? Thanks?

```
04-21 21:33:07.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-21 21:33:07.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020008
04-21 21:33:07.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:846)
04-21 21:33:07.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:534)
04-21 21:33:07.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:432)
04-21 21:33:07.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.initialize(IconMenuItemView.java:109)
04-21 21:33:07.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(786):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.createItemView(MenuItemImpl.java:586)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those folders like 'res/drawable-hdpi' where introduced first in Android 1.6. Android 1.5 only supports the 'res/drawable'-folder.

Comment: Lukas, I assume your last sentence should read "Android 1.5 ...".  So, this explains why Eclipse yields different folders under res when you create a new project and set your project to target a specific API version. I never made the connection, as I changed the API version after the project was created on my earlier projects.

Comment: Sorry, edited that. I think developing apps for Android 1.5 isn't necessary any more, because 1.5 runs on 3% of all Android Devices: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Google-more-than-92-of-Android-devices-running-2-1-or-later-1209432.html

Comment: My stats for my apps show about 1.7% of my users are on Android 1.5. I would really like to forget about it, too. Unfortunately, I had some nasty nanners give me some bad reviews, but I suppose I could just increase the Min SDK to Android 1.6 and be done with them. At any rate, you definietly helped me out. Thanks!